# Tkinter Canvas - Resetting Image/Scroolbar Position After Scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

The code below creates a simple slide show that allows the user to scroll around the image. When I load a second image, it is placed on the canvas where the first one was placed (say, off centre after scrolling). But I would like the second image to be centred in the canvas. I realize that is is because the scrollbar position is kept, even after updating the image. So, my question is, how do I reset the scrollbar positions so the second image is centred. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
class App:
#######################################
    def imgBack(self):
        if (self.imPointer!=0 and len(self.imageList)>0):
            self.imPointer -= 1
            self.imgChange(self.imageList[self.imPointer])
#######################################
    def imgChange(self, imgFile):
# /3482081/ /46043544/
        img = os.path.join(imgFile)
        self.im = tk.PhotoImage(file = img)
# I would have thought that the x, y and anchor would have re-centred the image but it keeps the pisition of the previous image
        self.icanvas.create_image(self.icWidth/2,self.icHeight/2, image=self.im, anchor='center') # /64042943/
#######################################
    def imgForward(self):
        if (self.imPointer<len(self.imageList)-1 and len(self.imageList)>0):
            self.imPointer += 1
            self.imgChange(self.imageList[self.imPointer])
#######################################
    def __init__(self, root):
        w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = root.winfo_screenheight()
        root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' %(w,h))
# Variables
        self.imPointer = 0
        self.imageFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.imageFrame.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
        self.imageList = ['image1.png','image2.png']
# Image Widgets
        self.icWidth = 900; self.icHeight = 700
        self.icanvas = tk.Canvas(self.imageFrame, width = self.icWidth, height = self.icWidth, background='white')
        self.im = tk.PhotoImage()
        self.icanvas.create_image(self.icWidth/2,self.icHeight/2, image=self.im, anchor='center') # /64042943/
        self.icanvas.grid(row=0,column=1, rowspan = 30, columnspan = 19, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.iyscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.icanvas, orient = tk.VERTICAL) # /60435842/
        self.iyscrollbar.config(command = self.icanvas.yview)
        self.iyscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill = 'y')
        self.ixscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.icanvas, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.icanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.iyscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = self.ixscrollbar.set) # /32290043/
        self.ixscrollbar.config(command = self.icanvas.xview)
        self.ixscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill = 'x')
        self.ibkbutton = ttk.Button(self.imageFrame, text='<', command = self.imgBack)
        self.ibkbutton.grid(row=33, column=19, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.ifwdbutton = ttk.Button(self.imageFrame, text='>', command = self.imgForward)
        self.ifwdbutton.grid(row=33, column=20, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='nsew')
        for i in range(0,30):
            self.imageFrame.rowconfigure(i,weight=1, uniform=1)
            if i<21:
                self.imageFrame.columnconfigure(i,weight=1, uniform=1)
#######################################
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can directly call methods on the scrollbars, and you can directly call the `xview` and `yview` methods of the canvas? You also should readjust the `scrollregion` if your images are different sizes.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan, I wasn't  aware, so I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I avoided the problem by recoding to use the method shown at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4zePg2M5H8